# In App Billing (To purchase a Module inside application)

Tags: java, android, product, in-app-billing

What I need to do is to create an application in which few of the segments should be invisible for user in published version.However when user checkouts In App billing purchase module he would be able to access these segments(Which is basically a number of Screens).

As of Now I am able to integrate the Standard In-App billing demo application in my application.But I am still confused how to make these Segments available for the purchaser as soon as he successfully checkout through In-App billing module. I am afraid of publishing app as it is recommended as per Android Developer Guide. I've a perception in my mind that how it would be working but want to take live experience.

Can anybody tell me the proper procedure and guidance for testing the Application apparently before it to be delivered to client.

Any help would be highly appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to enter demo users for In app billing. You can enter the email ids with testing privileges there.

Go to Settings tab in Developer Console where you'll find "Gmail accounts with testing access", which is defined as:

> License Testing - In addition to the owner of this console the following users will get the License test response from the application. They can also make in-app purchases from APKs that have been uploaded but not been published yet.

Answer (score 0):

Go through with this link :

[Implementing In-app Billing (IAB Version 3)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

It is having good explanation with good piece of example code.

You can set up test accounts also to test in-app before delivered to client.

[Setting Up Test Accounts](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup)

Thanks.